# How to typecast map.getValue() to ArrayList<Integer>()?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, casting

What I want do is, store the indexes in the arraylist of the current element in which it repeats, I have done that and now I want to check.

```
HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> hmap = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            if(!hmap.containsKey(arr[i]))
            {
                ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<>();
                hmap.put(arr[i],a1);
            }
            else
                hmap.get(arr[i]).add(i);
        }

        for(Map.Entry m:hmap.entrySet())
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> alist = {Here it is showing erorr.}m.getValue();
            System.out.println(m.getKey()+" ");
            for(int i=0;i<alist.size();i++) 
                System.out.print(alist.get(i)+" ");
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to specify your [generic types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) (same as in Map) in foreach loop.

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> m : hmap.entrySet())
```